# MongoDB using $exists and $and still return documents without field

Tags: database, mongodb

I have flat objects stored in mongo and one of them have the field00048 attribute but my query is still returning entries without field00048. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my mongo query? I have attached a picture of the database below to show the structure.

```
db.QA_Book_01.find({ 
    field00048: { $exists: true }},
    {
        $and:[
            { 'entryTypeId': 'Entry_Type_01' },
            { 'field00048': { $ne : 'Closed' }}]
    }).count();
```

Out of 3 records, there is only one with the field 'field00048'. When I change the entryTypeId to Entry_Type_02, it still retrieves the record with the field 'field00048'. Not sure what's going on here.
[image]

Comment: At a first glance it would appear you have a bracket too much after the `$exists: true` so the second bit with the `$and` actually gets interpreted as a projection - not sure how that would even work but still. ;)

Comment: Couple of typos really, and FYI your query would be `db.QA_Book_01.find({ field00048: { $exists: true, $ne: 'Closed' }, 'entryTypeId': 'Entry_Type_01' })`. ALL conditions are in implicit "AND" as well as multiple conditions on the "right side" of a property are also an "AND" condition for the same field. There are *very rare* cases where you actually need to write `$and`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is an and operation in find query of MongoDB so the proper syntax for applying an `and` operation in `find` query is mentioned below.

```
db.users.find( { $and: [ {field00048: { $exists: true }}, 
        { 'entryTypeId': 'Entry_Type_01' },
        { 'field00048': { $ne : 'Closed' }} ] } )
```

Comment: I think query should be look like as above displayed